# Taking n lines from a file which contains m lines, repeating the file (lazily) if necessary

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, boost-hana

I'm looking for a way to use a text file to generate as much text as I need by simply repeating the as few times as needed.

In a purely functional language, like Haskell, the solution seems trivial: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245495/taking-n-lines-from-a-file-which-contains-m-lines-repeating-the-file-lazily-if) I've posted the code for the review, and it is pretty short, even though I'm pretty sure it can be improved.

But in C++, I have little clue of where to start from, except that I'm pretty sure Boost Hana offers a lot of the tools I need to design the solution.

Here's an example input file,

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

and, if I ask for 7 lines, here's what I'd like to put in a variable (for instance in a single `std::string` with embedded `'\n'`s),

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
```

I guess the function can have a declaration like this:

```cpp
std::string function(std::string s, int n);
```

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking for exactly. But you can loop through a text file reading whole lines using `std::ifstream` with `std::getline()` until you want to stop reading lines.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, is it clearer now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `file` is some input stream, and you want to repeat the lines in `file` for `n` lines, you can use the range-v3 library like this:

```cpp
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto lines = ranges::getlines(file) 
           | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>;
  
auto result = lines 
            | rv::cycle
            | rv::take(n) 
            | rv::join('\n') 
            | ranges::to<std::string>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5enP3).

Comment: You stole my thunder. This is what a Haskell programmer would expect at the very least.

Comment: Woooooooooooow.

Answer (score 1):

To do that in C++, you would need to loop similar to the following:

```cpp
std::string readLines(std::string filename, int nlines)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename);
    std::string line, result;

    while (nlines > 0)
    {
        while (std::getline(in, line))
        {
            result += line;
            result += '\n';
            if (--nlines == 0)
                return result;
        }

        if (!in) // an error occurred...
            break; // or throw...

        // must be eof, rewind and start over...

        in.clear(); // <-- seekg() clears eofbit in C++11 and later...

        if (!in.seekg(0)) // an error occurred...
            break; // or throw...
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this approach suffer from repeated reallocation of `result`?

Comment: `std::string` has a `capacity` that grows in chunks, so it doesn't need to reallocate memory on every individual append. If you have an idea of how much memory you will need (for instance, in your example, `6 * nLines`), you can also `reserve()` the string's memory ahead of time to reduce reallocations as well.

Comment: Does `seekg()` actually reset the stream error state from eof?

Comment: @sehe [in C++11 and later, yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg): "*Before doing anything else, seekg clears eofbit. (since C++11)*"